# Enable Citrix UI after disconnect

Tags: citrix, vdi

I have my VDI machine on which I am trying to run Selenium Tests. All works well when I am connected (via Citrix Workspace) however when I'm not connected (when I disonnect) the "screen" turns blank - all my tests fail. I guess the desktop gets locked.
Can I somehow keep the screen functional ?

Answer (score 0):

you can check with VDI admins if there is any screen lock policy applied on VDIs. Though it is not recommended in a corporate environment, there are some third-party utilities that may help. Please check this. It may help.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Citrix/comments/byen5y/keeping_a_citrix_reciever_session_alive_avoiding/